# ToolTips binding messed up when grid is sorted

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, tooltip, telerik-grid

I have telerik grid control bound to ViewModel. One of the properties can contain relatively long string that is hard to fit into grid. So I am displaying the cell as a TextBlock with TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" and show the full text in the ToolTip control:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="TaskDetails" DataMemberBinding="{Binding TaskDetails}" Header="Task details"  IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" >
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskDetails}" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="300000" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Height="30">
                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Width="350" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding TaskDetails}" />
                    </ToolTip>
                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Everything works fine until user sort the grid. If the sorting applied the TextBlock shows correct data but the tooltip shows the text of the cell that previously was at that position. Like it not been sorted.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using custom control in my grid:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="TaskDetails" 
                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding TaskDetails}" 
                        Header="Task details"  
                        Width="500"
                        IsReadOnly="True">
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <cc:LongTextBlock Text="{Binding TaskDetails}" ToolTipShowDuration="300000" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTipWidth="350" />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Where the LongTextBlock is simple control with 3 dependency properties:

```
public class LongTextBlock : Control
{

static LongTextBlock()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LongTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LongTextBlock)));
}


#region DependencyProperty Text of LongTextBlock

public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(LongTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

#endregion

#region DependencyProperty ToolTipShowDuration of LongTextBlock

public int ToolTipShowDuration
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ToolTipShowDurationProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ToolTipShowDurationProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipShowDurationProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTipShowDuration", typeof(int), typeof(LongTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(10000));

#endregion

#region DependencyProperty ToolTipWidth of LongTextBlock

public double ToolTipWidth
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ToolTipWidthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ToolTipWidthProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipWidthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTipWidth", typeof(double), typeof(LongTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(350.0));

#endregion
}
```

and the style for the control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LongTextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LongTextBlock}">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="{TemplateBinding ToolTipShowDuration}">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Width="{TemplateBinding ToolTipWidth}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                        </ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, although with a different grid. 
The datatemplate contained an user control, and inside we had this:

```
public WebSnapshotCell()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.ToolTipOpening += new ToolTipEventHandler(WebSnapshotCell_ToolTipOpening);
}

void WebSnapshotCell_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
  // Refresh tooltip's data context
  ToolTip tooltip = this.ToolTip as ToolTip;
  if (tooltip != null)
  {
    tooltip.DataContext = this.DataContext;
  }
}
```

In your case, you can try to put the TextBox in a UserControl, or handle the ToolTipOpening event in another way, or explicitly binding the ToolTip's DataContext to the TextBlock's DataContext